# Circles created by points inside bounding box query - PostGIS

Tags: postgis, intersection, query, extents

The table that i want to perform this query has 3 columns: id, the_geom and seen_count.

The query i've been using to get points inside a bounding box is as follows:

```
SELECT id, ST_AsGeoJSON(the_geom) FROM table WHERE ST_Contains(ST_MakeEnvelope({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, 4326), table.the_geom)
```

What i want to do is: selecting points, which are transformed to circles using their seen_count as radius, intersect with bounding box. Is it possible? If so, would it be an expensive query? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wrap the table.geom in ST_Buffer() using the seen_count column as buffer distance, like so:  SELECT id, ST_AsGeoJSON(the_geom) FROM table WHERE ST_Contains(ST_MakeEnvelope({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, 4326), ST_Buffer(table.the_geom, table.seen_count)).  I guess you realize that ST_Contains will return the ids only of points where the buffered circle it *totally* within the bounding box.

Comment: Thank you for showing me a starting point. I found the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Micha, i found the answer:

```
SELECT id, ST_AsGeoJSON(the_geom) FROM table WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(ST_MakeEnvelope({0}, {1}, {3}, {4}, 4326), 
ST_Buffer(the_geom::geography, 1000*(seen_count+1))::geometry);
```